# Using both jsp:usebean and jsf managed beans?

Tags: jsp, jsf, javabeans

I am right now evaluating our options to migrate a web application which uses really smelly JSP with scriptlets and many disgusting design choices to JSF2 with Facelets. As the application is too big to do it in one go, I will have to have both technologies working side by side for some time.

The JSPs use `jsp:usebean` a lot. In order to get the old smelly JSPs and my new shiny Facelets to work together I would need to also include the same beans. Has anyone faced a similar scenario? Can I just put the `@ManagedBean` annotation on the bean with scope session, and the same bean will be used by JSP and facelets alike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider separating out the JSF backing beans and removing the `jsp:usebeans` later on since the usebean tags and JSF tags could further clutter the JSPs but it would be additional maintenance if the usebeans are not cleaned out.

If you propose to leave the usebeans as it is, go ahead as per your approach. Else segregate the managed beans for now  and clean the code slowly.